# Use of w3c web assembly API call a native assembly installed on a computer or device

Tags: assembly, web, browser, interop

Is it possible to use the web assembly API to call a native assembly (i.e. dll) installed on a computer or device from a browser that supports the web assembly API?

Comment: While I'm not familiar with web assembly, I'm pretty sure this isn't possible.  I don't think there is any way to execute native code at all as that's one of the reasons why web assembly was developed in the first place.